# Is it possible to programmatically connect to a chromecast route?

Tags: html, chromecast

I'm writing a chromecast receiver application that will (hopefully) allow me to remotely put alert messages up on my TV to serve as reminders.

My plan was to have a dedicated wireless device on my home network that would constantly poll for new messages from a centralized server. When a new message was found, it would connect to a chromecast route, turning on the TV and displaying the new message.

But as far as I can tell, the only way to activate a chromecast route is by manually clicking the chromecast icon on my Chrome browser or wireless device.

Is there a way, programmatically, to activate the chromecast? Can it be done in the sender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can programmatically scan for cast devices and connect to them if needed. Steps are:

1. Get an instance of the MediaRouter singleton from the system: `mMediaRouter`
2. Build a selector:
   `mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
           .addControlCategory(
                   CastMediaControlIntent
                           .categoryForCast(YOUR_APP_ID)).build();`
3. Add a callback to initiate scan:
   `mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
               MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);`
4. The `onRouteAdded()` and `onRouteRemoved()` of your callback (i.e. `mMediaRouterCallback`) will be called as routes are discovered or removed. You can maintain a list of routes in your app and keep them up to date by using these two callbacks.
5. You can select a route by calling `mMediaRouter.selectRoute(aRouteInfo)`. Then the `onRouteSelected()` of your callback will be called and you can extract the cast device as usual and do as you please.

These said, remember that if you want to show a notification to users on TV your app should be running on the chromecast at the time you want to send the notification.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in marking as answer. When I originally asked this question, I hadn't actually tried making an _android_ sender (only chrome) so I didn't know whether to mark it or not. After finally making an Android sender, your solution does appear to work for Android.

By any chance are you aware of a way to programmatically select a route in a chrome sender?