# How to cast youtube video from my android device to chromecast programatically using custom receiver?

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, google-cast

I need to search videos via any keyword and display selected video on chromecast. I did the first part using Youtube API where I am getting video id of search content in JSON. I need custom receiver as I need to display some more stuff like  image. I am able to send custom messages to a receiver . Now how to proceed further to cast selected video. I read about iframe API but still confused. Please guide me steps how to do this on both sender and receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the iframe api will help in your attempt to cast programatically, since casting is taken care of in the Cast SDK and Media Player Library. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706041/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-chromecast-route) which very clearly blocks out the steps you need take.