# Android Video Pushed To Internet TV

Tags: android

I've got an application with Exoplayer. Works perfectly.

A request came to implement the "Cast to TV" (like the Apple TV Icon you get at the bottom when an Apple TV is present in the same network)

I've been trying to read up on this for Android, though seem to get lost be different information by different contradictions.

Some talk about a sender and receiver app, but i'm pretty sure this would not be needed as I have seen other apps where i can just push to the tv without having to install other software on the tv or whatever. (I understand that these TV's must comply to some certain standard)

Surely there is a way to:
Put a cast button at the top
Press it and show a selection screen of devices available
Then tell the player to "cast to tv"
(simply said of course)

Does anyone know of clear information and/or sample?
Please don't link to the Android pages, because that's one of the reasons I got lost in this matter.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html
has no mention of needing another app.

What is allShare? Only for samsung or is there a universal standard?

Thank you to the person who will take the time to explain and provide some insight to where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to programmatically connect to a chromecast route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706041/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-chromecast-route)

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked.

Comment: It's not what you asked but the answer to that question applies here *I think*