# Programmatically connect to a chromecast route: do I need a permission?

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I want to connect to chromecast route programmatically, just as posted here: [Is it possible to programmatically connect to a chromecast route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706041/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-chromecast-route)

When doing so (calling `mMediaRouter.selectRoute(aRouteInfo)`), I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null media projection manager`.

However, when selecting my chromecast receiver via the chromecast button from the popup list, then disconnecting and then calling `mMediaRouter.selectRoute(aRouteInfo)` again, it works fine.

I assume I have to ask for some kind of permission before. Anyone knows what to do in this case?

The exception will be thrown in this line ...

```
mProjection = ((MediaProjectionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE)).getMediaProjection(permissionsResultCode, permissionsData);
```

... the parameter permissionData (Intent) seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I found the (newbie)problem. I just had to create the Intent by myself and react on this within "onActivityResult".